# Accessing variables from other functions javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

am new in java script, am sorry if Q stupid.
in my code i have a center position with lat and long , i hava another function to update the center position .
the problem: i want to change marker position from center position to new center position when call pan() function.

```
var panPoint;

function myMap() {
    var Center = new google.maps.LatLng(32.224063, 35.230539);
    var mapProp = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: Center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var canvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Center
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap);

function pan() {
    panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
    map.panTo(panPoint)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the marker position also, you need to make the reference to it global (like you did with `panPoint`), define it outside of any functions, remove the `var` from in front of it inside your `myMap` function.  Note that you also need to make `map` global as well, for the center to actually change.

```
var marker;

function myMap() {
  var Center = new google.maps.LatLng(32.224063, 35.230539);
  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: Center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var canvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
  map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapProp);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: Center
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Then move it when you call your `pan` function:

```
function pan() {
  panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
  marker.setPosition(panPoint);
  map.panTo(panPoint)
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b9gj8xtu/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var panPoint;
var map;
var marker;

function myMap() {
  var Center = new google.maps.LatLng(32.224063, 35.230539);
  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: Center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var canvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
  map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapProp);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: Center
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap);

function pan() {
  panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
  marker.setPosition(panPoint);
  map.panTo(panPoint)
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="lat" value="32.224063" />
<input id="lng" value="35.230539" />
<input id="btn" type="button" onClick="pan();" value="pan" />
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: i know my problem that small ,, i appreciate it for you.